# Short circuit recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

Is it possible to do the following without getting a stackoverflow?

```
int foo(int i = 0)
{
    return foo(--i) || i;
}
```

When `foo(--i`) evaluates to `0`, it should return false, therefore returning `i` and ending the execution.

Comment: `||` is a Boolean expression, so not what you want anyway. But this won't work since you always call `foo` before there is any chance to know if it should quit.

Comment: What's the real thing you're trying to do?

Comment: Try doing it on paper first, and you will see that it will not work.

Comment: When would `foo(--i)` evaluate to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `return !i || foo(--i)`.

Note that `||` is short-circutted. This means that evaluation (which is performed from left to right) will continue for only as long as the result of the expression is not known. So the way I've written it, the case `i` being zero will block the recursion.

(Moving on to more advanced issues, you need to be very careful when evaluating expressions when the same variable appears in more than one sub-expression and it's value is changed in some of them. My having `!i` and `--i` could get me in trouble: I'm not too far away from *undefined behaviour* here. In fact, it turns out that my code is completely safe since `||` is a *sequence point* and the order of evaluation with `||` is well-defined. But do be careful.)

Comment: Perhaps but the question is not that clear IMHO. I'll leave this answer in since it addresses the issues around evaluation and recursion blocking.

Comment: @Debasish Easy fix: `return !i && foo(--i);`

Answer (score -1):

From what you have coded  `foo` never returns because it will continuosly go on decreasing `i` and recurse. You need a check inside `foo` which returns whatever you want when you get `i` as `0`.

Comment: @DebasishJana It is copy paste of the question not an alternative answer

Comment: People downvoting please let me know what is wrong with the answer.